# How do you animate to top a centered Image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a simple webpage consisting of an image horizontally and vertically centered so it is displayed in the absolute center on the visible page.
I am trying to get this image to migrate to the top of the page using jQuery animate.

I have centered the image using two divs and some css.

html...

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"><img src="images/png/logo.png" id="logo-index" width="84px" height="100px"/></div>
</div>
```

css...

```
#outer{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
overflow: visible;
}

#inner{
width: 82px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: -41px;
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
left: 50%;
}

#logo-index{
opacity: 0;
}
```

The image is initially hidden using opacity 0 and faded in to view using jQuery. Then id like the image to move to the top of the page using jQuery animate.

jQuery...

```
$('#logo-index').animate({opacity: "1"}, 1500).delay(3000, function(){
    //jQuery move to top of page here...
});
```

Ive googled so many different methods im now totally confused about the correct way to achieve this. I dont have enough experience of the animate function to achieve this. Im sure someone out there does.

Answer (score 0):

Animate the #outer, because is the "container" of the image who has the 50% top position.

```
$('#logo-index').animate({opacity: "1"}, 1500).delay(3000, function(){
    //jQuery move to top of page here...
    $('#outer').animate({top:"10%"}, 1500);
});
```

Can be tested here: [jsfiddle live code to animate](http://jsfiddle.net/8PSbY/)

I hope it help!
Cheers

Comment: Thats great it does work. Can this be done for a fixed postion at the top and not percentage? I cant seem to get it to work for say 100px from the top.

Comment: Yeap!, you can, but in that case, you need to specify the top position of the #outer in px also. That is, css in px and $.animate in px (or both in %)

Comment: Or use jQuery v1.8.0 that allready fix that bug and let you mix percentage and pixels in animate function.